# Accessing structures from different files in C

Tags: c, struct

I have the following C code

File Name: abc.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct abc{
int xxx;
float yyy;
};
```

I need to access the above struct in another file called def.c

Could anybody explain me how i can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You move the definition to a header file (.h suffix), and include it in both abc.c and def.c

Comment: The definition by default is extern. So this structure is available in the same compilation unit. It's better to define it in a header file and include the header file in both the .c files.

Comment: you can use #include "abc.c" on the def.c file.

Answer (score 7):

```
// mystructs.h
struct abc{
    int xxx;
    float yyy;
};


//abc.c
#include "mystructs.h"
struct abc var1;


//another_file.c
#include "mystructs.h"
struct abc var2;
```

Comment: A few words would be nice, even if only to break up the code blocks.

Comment: @ams, Is that a compliment?

Comment: It's a suggestion on how to write better quality answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
//myheader.h

struct abc{

int xxx;

float yyy;

}obj;
```

```
//demo.c
# include"myheader.h"

# include"stdio.h"

int main(){

printf("\nENTER TWO VALUES : ");

scanf("%d %f",&obj.xxx,&obj.yyy);

printf("\nVALUES YOU ENTERED ARE : %d %f\n",obj.xxx,obj.yyy);

return 0;

}
```